# Source org(A) And destination org integration?

Tags: integration

I have a source org A and destination org as a B. Now i have integrated source org to destination org via rest api.

Now my questions are:-

1) What is the validity of access token?

2) If i retrieve Refresh token also then what is validity  of refresh token?

3) After storing this refresh token in custom setting, How many days we can use this refresh token to retrieve date from another org.?

4) When we will update our refresh token In custom setting?

Answer (score 1):

1. The access token will be valid as long as the target org is configured to keep sessions valid so there's no way to know the validity though it's best to assume it is a short time period where you need to handle expiration.
2. Refresh tokens are permanent.  They only become invalid if the access is revoked from the target org.
3. You can't use the refresh token to make API calls.  You can use the refresh token to request a new access token which can be used to make API calls.
4. That's your call, but I'd think you only need to do this once or if the refresh token gets revoked from the target org for some reason.

You can find a lot of these details in the following help article:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_refresh_token_oauth.htm

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Is refresh token expired after org password change.

Comment: Like today my password is  pass123, this time i will get refresh token and store this token in custom setting after two three days i will chnage my password this time my refresh token will expire or not.

Comment: Refresh tokens do not expire after password change like a security token does.  This is a nice advantage of refresh tokens for some use cases :)